# How can I see if RAM was failing after removing it from the Mac?

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I recently replaced some original 1GB RAM modules in my Mac Pro with 4GB ones. After a day or two of constant uptime, I attempted to reboot the machine which resulted in the power light blinking quickly (an indication that there is bad RAM). I removed the new RAM, replaced with the smaller modules that were there before and things were fine.

I have had bad RAM before as indicated by ECC failures in the System Information screens. However, before rebooting I didn't look at these screens so I don't have screenshot proof to send to the vendor that it is their modules at fault.

Is a RAM failure somewhere captured in the system logs?

Answer (score 1):

No, normally RAM failures such as the one you describe cannot be captured in system logs.

You should RMA the RAM modules as usual.